# How to omit the rightmost 30 display pixels of my MBPR display

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, display

I managed to damage my MacBook Pro Retina's screen. The rightmost 62 pixels are dead. Can I force the display on my Mac to identify itself as smaller as it actually is, so all programs using the display will simply not use the dead parts?

Other option: Is there a way to auto-resize all windows to not use that damaged part of the screen?